# I need to increase the snake's speed every time it eats

Tags: java, class, methods, game-engine, boolean-logic

the snake's speed is measured by two values, and I'm trying to increase it's speed each time it eats

I've played around with the Boolean methods and values, but I cant find the correct logic of what variable I should increase the value to, and which one I should decrease or leave it as it is

```java
    public class Player {
        public boolean justAte;

        public int moveCounter;
        public int speedManager;

        public Player(Handler handler){
            this.handler = handler;
            moveCounter = 0;
            speedManager = 5; // Whenever I increase this value, the  
                              // snake's initial speed gets slower
            justAte = false;
        }
        public void tick() {
            moveCounter += 1;
            if(moveCounter >= speedManager) {
                checkCollisionAndMove();
                moveCounter = 0;
            }
            /*
             * In the next if statement I attempted to increase the
             * snake's speed each time the Eat() method was being used
             * ;nevertheless, whenever I ate an apple the snake simply
             * went super fast and no change was seen if I ate again.
             */
            if (isJustAte()) { 
            checkCollisionAndMove();
            moveCounter += 5;
            }
        }
        public void Eat() {
            setJustAte(true); 
        }
        public boolean isJustAte() {
            return justAte; 
        }
        public void setJustAte(boolean justAte) {
            this.justAte = justAte; 
        }
    }
```

on the second if statement I tried to put (justAte = true) but the effect it had on the snake was ridiculous speed since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Decrease speedManager by 1.

But you can only do that 5 times, so after eating 5 foods, it will have constant speed which will be equal to 1 move per tick.
Movement in games is a bit more complicated than that. If you have access to delta-time between your ticks (difference between ticks measured in real time), you can change snake's speed much smoother by using floats. This way it will be not so heavily quantized by integer values and will depend on real time, instead of framerate

Answer (score 0):

You use increase move counter by one each tick. You move forward once it is greater/equal to `speedManager`. That means `speedManager` effectively equals the number of ticks between moves. Therefore increasing it will increase the wait between movements. If you want to go faster, you will have to **decrease** the wait.

Also, in your current logic, justAte will always equal true after being set, in gameTick you need to set it to false after increasing the movement speed to not increase it again.

With this logic you can't go faster than 1 movement per tick and you can't use speeds that are not integers. If you want more precose movement you would have to store the position as a floating point number (although displaying a rounded integer) and increase that one each tick based on the time. Most game engines work using a delta that indicates the amount of passed time.

Here's an example of what that would look like if you were just moving sth along one axis (1D) with a certain speed.

```
private static final int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 60;
private float position = 0.0f;
private float speed = 2.0f; // specified in per second in this case

/**
 * @param delta  the time passed since gameTick was called the last time in seconds (fraction of a second)
 */
public void gameTick(float delta) {
    //update game elements
    position += speed * delta;  // as speed is specified in distance per second we can just multiply it with the time passed (delta in seconds) and add that to the position
}

public void gameLoop() {
    long lastTick = System.currentTimeMillis(); // the time the last tick occured (in milliseconds since 1970)
    while(true) {
        try { Thread.sleep(1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND); } catch(InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } // tick rate will slightly undercut TICKS_PER_SECOND as this wait doesn't correct for processing time
        long deltaMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTick; // milliseconds passed since the last tick

        //TODO: perform input

        //update
        gameTick((float)deltaMillis / 1000.0f);

        //TODO: render

        lastTick += deltaMillis; // by not using currentTime but the delta that was processed by gameTick, we keep an accurate time (not slowing down the game due to processing time in the gameTick method) 
    }
}
```